# Concatenate different length vectors

Tags: matlab

I am having difficulty concatenating vectors in MATLAB.

```
A = [1
     2
     3]

B = [6
     7
     8
     9
     10]

Desired result:

C = [1
     2
     3
     6 
     7                
     8
     9
     10]
```

where the sizes of `A` and `B` are different in every iteration of my script and I want to form the concatenated resulting vector, `C`, which has a dynamic size.

This is what I have tried:

[image: matlab snapshot]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: vertcat or horzcat along the direction of your vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
A = [1 2 3];
B = [4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

C = [A B]
```

For vertical vectors A' and B' use:

```
C = [A;B]
```

Comment: thanx for sharing this. Your answer in useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
A = [1
     2
     3];

B = [6
     7
     8
     9
     10];
```

*Vertical* concatenation of two vectors/matrices is what you want, done like this...

```
C = [A; B];
```

... or this...

```
C = [A
     B];
```

... or this...

```
C = vertcat(A,B);
```

All three of these give

```
C = [1
     2
     3
     6
     7 
     8
     9
     10]

% As you requested...
```

You were running into trouble because you were trying to use `horzcat`

```
C = horzcat(A',B');
```

*Horizontal* concatenation merges matrices horizontally, i.e.

```
C = [1, 6
     2, 7
     3, 8
     ?, 9
     ?, 10]
```

So to avoid this, you've transposed the matrices to make them rows instead of columns, then transposed the result back?? You just need `vertcat`! I have shown the shorthand and full form for this above.

Comment: thanx for sharing this. Your answer in useful.

Comment: @PreetiSingh then please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green/white tick in the top left corner of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The fool-proof way is this:

```
C = [A(:);B(:)];
```

If you use this method then it does not matter if A and B are row vectors, column vectors, or even matrices.

Comment: thanx for sharing this. Your answer in useful.

Comment: Whilst you're right, learning to always use this could be risky. In more complicated programs, using this blindly could completely mess up the dimensions of your matrices! Maybe elaborate as to what is happening with your method for better understanding:)